# EWS creating SearchFolder fails: ErrorEmailAddressMismatch

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

For a client, i've a set of shareMailboxes. From each of them I should collect all the item IPM.Note, within a specific range of time. 
For almost all of the mailboxes the code works fine. But for couple of them i've the following error:

> Microsof.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseExpeption: The email
>   address associated with a folder Id does not match the mailbox you are
>   operating on.

at the following link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.serviceerror?view=exchange-ews-api) i've found the explanation:

> "Occurs when the e-mail address for the distinguished folder ID does
>   not match the mailbox that you are operating on. For example, you
>   cannot create a search folder that exists in one mailbox but considers
>   distinguished folders from another mailbox in its search criteria."

it is still unclear to me how i could avoid this condition, while defining the searchCriteria.

Here is the code:

```
SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);
        SearchFolder searchFolder = new SearchFolder(searchfolderservice);

        // Defining the filters options. Specifically it is looking at the Class of the Message and select all the message that are IPM.Note* type
        searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "IPM.Note", ContainmentMode.Substring, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCase));

        // Defining the time window for the search criteria
        var START_DATE = Properties.Settings.Default.START_DATE;
        searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, START_DATE));
        var END_DATE = Properties.Settings.Default.END_DATE;
        searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsLessThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, END_DATE));

        //searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "picture attached"));
        searchFolder.DisplayName = SEARCHFOLDER_IPM_NOTE;
        searchFolder.SearchParameters.RootFolderIds.Add(SharedMailbox);
        searchFolder.SearchParameters.Traversal = SearchFolderTraversal.Deep;
        searchFolder.SearchParameters.SearchFilter = searchFilterCollection;
```

Comment: Are you creating the Search Folder in the Shared Mailbox or in another mailbox ? The error is telling you that your not creating the Search Folder in the Mailbox the search references.

Comment: I'm creating creating the search folder in the share mailbox, as per the other share mailboxes. it is possible that some items, are shared within more than one mailboxes, and this cause the exception ?